# Regex strip all html except background style url

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I have the following `regex` that will find all the background style URLs in my HTML. I'm trying to strip all the HTML except for the background image URLs. My goal is to abstract a list of background image URLs from my HTML page.

Expression `URL\(\s*(['"]?)(.*?)\1\s*\)`

Example HTML

```
<a href="#"><img style="background-image: url(http://domain.com/2003-Th.jpg)"></a>
```

I'd just like to do the not of this expression.

Comment: Most coding languages have an HTML parser that would be the correct answer.  Regex can be utilized for this but in most cases should not be used.

Comment: Where are you trying to do this or in what language? Also from the above code the output should be `http://domain.com/2003-Th.jpg`?

Comment: Trying to do it directly within the netbeans ide with regex replace all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know netbeans ide, so this is a guess only.

But beware: you search for `url(...)` everywhere. It does not matter where the text occurs: in a css block, in html style-attributes, in javascript, but also in pure text and comments!

## General modifications

If you really want to include background-images only, you should state that in your regex, too. So it becomes

```
\bbackground-image\s*:\s*URL\(\s*(['"]?)(.*?)\1\s*\)
```

To speed things up (at least in some implementations), try to prevent backreferences. In this case

```
\bbackground-image\s*:\s*URL\(\s*(?:'([^']+)'|"([^"]+)"|([^)]+))\s*\)
```

It's a bit more, but at least in sublime text it's worth it.

## Use

To replace everything but the urls from background-images, you could use the single regex

```
[\s\S]*?\bbackground-image\s*:\s*URL\(\s*(?:'([^']+)'|"([^"]+)"|([^)]+))\s*\)|[\s\S]+
```

and replace everything with `$1$2$3\n`. There are (almost) always two `\n` at the end, but I think that should be no problem.

This won't work in some regex engines where the not the order of the elements is decisive, but the length of the match.

However, if it's a problem, you can try to use

```
[\s\S]*?\bbackground-image\s*:\s*URL\(\s*(?:'([^']+)'|"([^"]+)"|([^)]+))\s*\)[\s\S]*?(?=\z|\bbackground-image\s*:\s*URL\(\s*(?:'[^']+'|"[^"]+"|[^)]+)\s*\))
```

and replace everything with `$1$2$3\n`.

- `[\s\S]` means every character (including `\n`)
- `\b` is a word boundary
- `(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead. It has to match but is not part of the result
- `\z` is the end of the text

(maybe you have to tweak the regex a bit to fit into netbeans)

Anyway, not every regex implementeation supports lookaheads. If this is not supported by netbeans, you have to use a multi-step approach:

#### First step

Replace

```
[\s\S]*?\bbackground-image\s*:\s*URL\(\s*(?:'([^']+)'|"([^"]+)"|([^)]+))\s*\)
```

with `>-BG-URL:$1$2$3\n`.

`>-BG-URL:` is something to indicate the values and distinct them from the rest.

#### Second step

Manually replace everything after the last match (you won't need `--BG-URL` then) or replace

```
^>-BG-URL:(.*)|^[\s\S]+
```

with `$1`